# Extract Value from Column in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have a database in which a particular column in a table has its values with braces {789-uiuiun-990..} of type (varchar(128),null).

Is there a way to write a query that gives me results by removing those braces.

```
i.e. select col from db ; ---> results with braces
```

How could I modify it to extract the value only and remove the braces .

Thanks

Comment: try `Select LEFT(RIGHT(col, len(col)-1),len(col)-2) from db` expecting braces are always first and last char

Comment: Will you please explain this? Means how this query will give expected result?

Comment: @RahulParit Just the column with its values having the braces removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using right and left functions to cut the charachter at first and last

```
Select LEFT(RIGHT(col, len(col)-1),len(col)-2) from db
```

You can also use substring + len function to achieve the same as below

```
Select substring(col,2,(LEN(col)-2)) from db
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the SQL REPLACE Function to replace all braces with empty spaces.

code sample of removing it

```
Declare @var varchar(100) = '{this is a value}'

Select REPLACE(REPLACE(@var,'{',''), '}','')
```

your value:

```
Select REPLACE(REPLACE(col,'{',''), '}','') from db
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, 2, LEN(col) - 2) AS 'col' FROM db
```

In general, this is where you'd find a solution to such a problem: [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @S varchar(128)
set @S='{789-uiuiun-990..5567}'
select substring (@s,2,LEN(@s)-2)
```